# ASP.NET Report Viewer LocalReport - SQL Query DataSet JOIN value empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, localreport

I'm doing a basic MVC apps and i'm trying to export the value of my SQL query to an Excel.
When i open the Excel file the 2 fields that are part of the JOIN are empty and i dont undertand why since when i click on Preview data on my DataSet i see the correct result.

[image]

But in my Excel file i dont see the TitleDescription and the TeamDescription.

[image]

My SQL Query:
Select Emp.EmployeeID, Emp.FirstName, Emp.LastName, Ti.TitleDescription, Te.TeamDescription,
Emp.Phone FROM Employees Emp
JOIN Titles Ti ON Emp.TitleID=Ti.TitleID
JOIN Teams Te ON Emp.TeamID=Te.TeamID

My Method:

```
    public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType)
    {
        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/EmployeeReport.rdlc");

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Name = "EmployeeReportDataSet";
        reportDataSource.Value = db.Employees.ToList();
        localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);       
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension = "XLSX";
     
        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        byte[] renderedByte;
        renderedByte = localreport.Render("EXCELOPENXML", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=employee_report." + fileNameExtension);
        return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);

    }
```

I believe my problem is comming from       reportDataSource.Value = db.Employees.ToList(); i should use DataTable1 instead of Employees but i'm not sure how.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem,

First i used a DataSet TableAdapter instead of the a DataSet Query and i used the method that was generated by default which is the GetData() method. I put it in the DataSource.Value=

Here's my corrected code:

```
        public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType)
    {
    
        EmployeeReportDataSet employeeReportDataSet = new EmployeeReportDataSet();

        EmployeeReportDataSetTableAdapters.TempReportTableAdapter employeereportTableAdapter =
            new EmployeeReportDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesReportsTableAdapter();

      employeereportTableAdapter.Fill(employeeReportDataSet.TempReport);

        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/EmployeeReport.rdlc");

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Name = "EmployeeReportDataSet";
        reportDataSource.Value = employeereportTableAdapter.GetData(); 
        localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);       
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension = "XLSX";
     
        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        byte[] renderedByte;
        renderedByte = localreport.Render("EXCELOPENXML", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=employee_report." + fileNameExtension);
        return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);

    }
```